# Any way to replicate Facebook Messenger chat bubbles border-radius, from a single list?

Tags: css

[image]
So in Messenger, for every first and last message they have special rounded borders giving a pretty neat visual style.

I'm trying to replicate this in a single list (Facebook uses separate containers), without any JS.

I've got separate classes for the left/right dynamic, so I can use .left + .right {} selector and the reverse to style the first message of every "stack". But I can't seem to select the last one in any way. Also every single message has an all-round border. Couldn't do that either, yet.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256877/how-to-create-chat-bubbles-like-facebook-messenger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create chat bubbles like facebook Messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256877/how-to-create-chat-bubbles-like-facebook-messenger)