# How to add border-radius before specific class of <li> for chat UI

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement chat bubble CSS from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257283/4824607), the problem is I don't know how to give `border-bottom-left-radius` to the first third message by other user and `border-bottom-right-radius` to the fourth message by this user. Please run this code snippet to understand what I'm saying. Thanks in advance.

```css
.chat-ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chat-ul .chat-li{
  display:inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.incoming {
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
}

.outgoing{
  float: right;
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}

.incoming:first-child{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.outgoing:first-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.incoming + .outgoing{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.outgoing + .outgoing{
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.outgoing:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}

.outgoing + .incoming{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.incoming + .incoming{
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.incoming:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul  class='chat-ul' style='margin-top: 10px'>
 <li class="chat-li incoming">By Other User, first message</li>
 <li class="chat-li incoming">By Other User, second message</li>
 <li class="chat-li incoming">By Other User, third message</li>
 <li class="chat-li outgoing">By this User, first message</li>
 <li class="chat-li outgoing">By this User, secondmessage</li>
 <li class="chat-li outgoing">By this User, third message</li>
 <li class="chat-li outgoing">By this User, fourth message</li>
 <li class="chat-li incoming">By Other User, first message</li>
 <li class="chat-li incoming">By Other User, second message</li>
 <li class="chat-li incoming">By Other User, third message</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you able to wrap them inside separate `<ul>` depending on who the message is from?

Comment: he already added the link, and this is not duplicated because the other answer is not the right one for this

Comment: Your css shouldn't work because the css tags shouldn't work that way. last-of-type tag will only work on element selectors not class selectors. In my opinion you need to wrap them with another div/ul otherwise selecting the specific element dynamically is not possible in your scenario unless you use some js.

Comment: In CSS that is not possible, you need to wrap each group of the messages in a separate wrapper. So you have to do the wrapping at server side.

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is more simple then you think. First, if you want to have this a flexible as possible put each "user-chat-item-history" in a separate `<ul>` with the class for `.outgoing` or `.incoming`. Therefore you need less `CSS` and the whole script is way more maintainable:

```css
.chat-ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chat-ul .chat-li {
  display:inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.incoming .chat-li {
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px 30px 30px 5px;
}

.outgoing .chat-li{
  float: right;
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px 5px 5px 30px;
}

.incoming .chat-li:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}

.incoming .chat-li:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.outgoing .chat-li:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

.outgoing .chat-li:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul  class='chat-ul incoming' style='margin-top: 10px'>
 <li class="chat-li">By Other User, first message</li>
 <li class="chat-li">By Other User, second message</li>
 <li class="chat-li">By Other User, third message</li>
</ul>

<ul  class='chat-ul outgoing' style='margin-top: 10px'>
 <li class="chat-li">By this User, first message</li>
 <li class="chat-li">By this User, secondmessage</li>
 <li class="chat-li">By this User, third message</li>
 <li class="chat-li">By this User, fourth message</li>
</ul>

<ul  class='chat-ul incoming' style='margin-top: 10px'>
 <li class="chat-li">By Other User, first message</li>
 <li class="chat-li">By Other User, second message</li>
 <li class="chat-li">By Other User, third message</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Adding `<ul>` would require additional js logic when pushing/adding new message or retrieving history, but certainly would make css easier to read and maintain.